# [GTK]Is it possible to achieve Glass/Blur effect in GTK?

Tags: gtk, user-experience

I was wondering if it's possible for any widgets to acquire MacOS-like blurry transparent background. Deepin Desktop Environment is able to emulate [this](https://ibb.co/bsQRx5) on their context menu with Qt. Windows is slowly adopting [this style](https://www.windowscentral.com/sites/wpcentral.com/files/styles/xlarge/public/field/image/2017/05/people-app-neon1.jpg?itok=9s-wvHtv) after they dropped aero.

Also, I was wondering if there's any way to ship a GTK application that do not follow user themes/fonts in *nix desktops so I can lock it down with my own CSS style.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, that's not available in GTK.

Answer (score 5):

not yet, but there is currently in development a gskblurnode event in GTK 4.0+, the dev build is 3.91.2. which i've seen a demo as well.
keep track of development here https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Roadmap/GTK4

and there is a video on youtube here with the demo. which also uses vulkan as the new renderer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gqo8nJKjcis