# How to add blur effect with transparent gnome terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome, gnome-terminal

Can't find any way to add a blur effect with gnome-terminal. Lots of tools available for other ubuntu-desktop environments such as KDE neon, KDE plasma.
I tried this way [blur the terminal in GNOME](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/7zcsl2/is_there_any_way_to_blur_the_terminal_in_gnome/). But this is not working.

Answer (score 10):

Currently this not a feature on Gnome terminal (January 2021) by default.

Just like this [post has stated.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954563/how-do-i-make-the-background-of-transparent-terminal-windows-blurry-in-ubuntu-gn)

You could probably try something like the Compiz compositor as I'm pretty sure they have a feature to blur windows if you are using a regular window manager.

From my experience with the Compiz compositor, it doesn't always work but its worth a try. I think that windows have to be somewhat transparent for you to see the blur so make sure to try that.

If you are using a tiling window manager (i3, DWM, etc.), you could try out the Compton compositor.

Here are some useful videos on the **Compton** compositor:

1. [How to install the Compton compositor and a quick look at how to get the transparency effect.](https://youtu.be/3OUzJs3aCBw)
2. [How to get the blur effect using Compton](https://youtu.be/Qng0lPIat-Y?t=66)

One final thing, I found an old thread on stack overflow that you probably found yourself.

[[GTK]Is it possible to achieve Glass/Blur effect in GTK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456175/gtkis-it-possible-to-achieve-glass-blur-effect-in-gtk)

Saying that people might be able to do the blur stuff in GTK 4.0+.
The link to the roadmap is kinda broken so here is another one.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK/Roadmap/GTK4

^ however, this wikipage is outdated and was moved [to a new milestones page](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/milestones/1)

The milestones page doesn't have any issues related to the blur affect you are looking for (there is only one thing about blurred shadows). So they probably just didn't move over all of the things listed in the old page.

I don't have enough knowledge to help you with the GTK stuff however, you are gonna have to explore that on your own.

I know I probably didn't help too much but this is all I could find.